# Can't populate array from cursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have got a function that fetches all data from the collection and should push to an array and then return the array.
The database is a mongoDB running locally.
The `items`(documents) fetch successfully and I can see it in the log. But the `result` array doesn't populate at all. It shows up as an empty array.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";


var findAll = () => {
    var result = []
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true },function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var cursor = db.db('music_db').collection("songDetails").find({})

        cursor.forEach((item, err) => {
            if (item === null) {
                cursor.close();
                return;
            }
            result.push(item)
            console.log(item.title);
        })
    });

    return result;
}

result = findAll();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get all the documents returned from mongoDB as an array, use `toArray()` method on `cursor`. For example:

```
// Get all values
const cursor = collection.find({});
const allValues = await cursor.toArray();
```

[Node.js MongoDB Driver API - toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Cursor.html#toArray)